# Cygwin : make install up to date problem

Tags: make, cygwin

I have installed **mingw-gcc: GNU Compiler Collection** using the setup of **Cygwin**. When running "make install" command :

```
$ make install
```

And I get this message :

```
make: `install' is up to date.
```

What might be the reasons? And how can I fix this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Windows determines which files are executable by their extension. Native executables must have the extension `.exe`. Cygwin contains some magic so that when you refer to a file `install` and there is no file by that name, it tries `install.exe`. It does this even in contexts that aren't about executing because when a program is looking up the metadata of a file, the library has no way to know whether the program intends to execute it later.

So if there is a file called `install.exe` in the current directory, `make` sees it and thinks that it is the target of the `install` rule. If `install.exe` is more recent than the prerequisites of the `install` rule, `make` determines (correctly from its point of view) that there is nothing to do.

You can add the line `.PHONY: install` to the makefile. That tells make that the `install` target is not a real file, and make will ignore any file by that name.

Alternatively, rename or move `install.exe` out of the way.

Comment: This applies too if there's no extension. Just happened to me with the INSTALL text file. Renamed and all good :)

Answer (score 1):

Usually this means that you already did `make install` and it doesn't need to do it again.

If you think you really should redo the build then try this:

```
make clean
make
make install
```

WARNING: That would be the *conventional* way to do it, but the author of your project may have had other ideas.